# Sharing UICollectionView data from 3 view controllers using MVC iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uicollectionview

This is the scenario.I am working on an app where there are 3 view controllers(say "child1","child2","child3") each with a collectionView on it.Now all of them have the same functionality.The only difference is that the data is coming from 3 different APIs.Now I have created a parent view controller(say "ParentVC") and all three viewControllers inherit "ParentVC".

Now suppose I arrive on "child1",API hits and collectionView is reloaded.
Now I push "child2",API hits and collectionView is reloaded.
Similar is the case with "child3".

Now when I pop "child3",the API on "child2" should not hit again.
Similar will be the case when I pop "child2".

Now I have managed to do that,but here is the problem.

PROBLEM:

I am trying to use MVC pattern,and I have a separate data model class which takes the data from API.Now how can I use MVC in this scenario,as the data model needs to be updated everytime I switch between view controllers and therefore the reload operation needs to be done?

Comment: Post some code what you have tried before? this will help to understand your situation and problem..

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to solve your problem

1- Try to call your API in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

2- If you are using MVC then you also need to implement two extra methods in your model classes called **encodeWithCoder** and **initWithCoder** and after getting response from API save your model objects Array or Dictionary in NSUSerDefaults using below code

`NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
    [prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

and get the saved object using below Code.

`NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [prefs objectForKey:key ];
    id obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];`

Comment: I have a single model class only.

Comment: Then you should have to take different objects of that model for each API data. And put the above mention methods of encoding and decoding in your model class.

Comment: Thats what I am doing.But I do not want to hit the API everytime I visit a view controller

Comment: Then use the second option.